# Jupyter notebook in sagemaker kernel keeps dying when I try to load data from s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

In sagemaker jupyter notebook I run the following code to load data from an s3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()
bucket='bucketname'
data_key = 'filename'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

data=pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

Then the kernel dies and I get a pop up saying "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Is there an easy way to load the data from s3 in sagemaker?

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: just under 2 gb @BrianJoseph

Comment: Hmmm that's fairly large. It could potentially be a lot of things but it's probably just too many rows for jupyter. Try loading your data in by chunks and doing processing like 1 chunk at a time: `for chunk in pd.read_csv(<filepath>, chunksize=<your_chunksize_here>)`

Comment: Thanks for you response, but is there not an easier way to do this? Isn't one of the points of sagemaker that I don't have to jump through hurdles in order to work with large amounts of data?

Comment: Which instance type are you using for your notebook? Can you try a bigger one? Also, consider using [Dask](https://dask.org/) for larger-than-memory data.

Comment: @Pavel thanks for this. I used a ml.t2.large instead of medium and it worked out.

Comment: @awrd2010 Remember if you find a solution, you can answer your own question rather than posting it in the comments

Answer (score 8):

It's most likely you created a notebook with too small of an instance. Most do `ml.t2.medium` for demos, but might need `ml.t2.large` or higher.

Remember that the `t2` is the second generation and it's guaranteed by AWS that further generations (`t3`) are **at least** as cost efficient as the prior generation. I.E. use a `ml.t3.medium` or `ml.t3.large`.

Comment: I was running an Amazon Neptune notebook , which actually is Sagemaker Notebook 
My Sagemaker Notebook instance was ml.t2.medium 
I had been running basic Neptune queries on the Notebook cells for few days but on a random day, I was facing this issue "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

I changed Sagemaker Notebook instance type to ml.t3.xlarge and issue disappeared. 

I think, in my case, Notebook instance type was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and contacted AWS customer service to increase the instance.